# Test if a file with a specific suffix exists using nio2

Tags: java, nio2

Given: a file named `example.xml` 
Aim: to test if the file `example.xml.sha256` exists.

What is the most elegant/efficient way to do this in Java 7+ (nio2, so using `java.nio.files`)?

I have this, but it looks a little bit ugly for me:

```
Path path = Paths.get("/../example.xml");
if (Files.exists(Paths.get(path.toString() + ".sha256")))) {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It'd be a little cleaner to use [`.resolveSibling()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#resolveSibling-java.nio.file.Path-), e.g.

```
path.resolveSibling(path.getFileName() + ".sha256");
```

This is not *dramatically* better than your solution, but it does have a few advantages:

1. The relationship between the two files is clearly documented by the code - they're siblings, sharing the same filename prefix.
2. It takes advantage of the features of `Path` - if you're just going to do direct string concatenations, you might as well not use `Path` at all.
3. It avoids `Paths.get()`, which is a suboptimal way to work with `Path`s (because it assumes the default filesystem).  Once you have a `Path`, you shouldn't ever need to re-call `Paths.get()`.

Comment: Okay, removed the use of `concat()` this virrvarrs the question. I know the `toString()` is redundant, but it shows why i think my solution is a little ugly. Why is your solution cleaner?

Comment: @rmuller I added a few reasons.  There's nothing wrong with string concatenations *when working with strings* (a filename on its own is a string), but when working with *paths* we can do better by taking advantage of the utilities in `Path`.